# How to use Redis pipelining?

Tags: redis, quarkus, mutiny

I would like to know how to use/control the Quarkus reactive Redis client with pipelining (ReactiveRedisDataSource). I understand the client does pipelining by default, but how can we control how many commands are pipelined before the request is sent? For example:

```java
    @Inject
    ReactiveRedisDataSource reactiveDS;
    
    // some code below ...
    
    reactiveDS.list(String.class).lpush("myList", "randomString")
      .chain(() -> reactiveDS.hash(String.class).hset("myKey", "field1", "randomValue"))
```

Does the code above pipelines those 2 commands? If not then how can I pipeline? If yes, how can I control how many messages can I enqueue before sending and how can I get the array response?

**UPDATE**

This is the suggested way to do it, it works! (see this thread: https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-mutiny/issues/1099):

```java
rds.withConnection(redis -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                unis.add(redis.value(Integer.class).set("key-" + i, i));
            }
            return Uni.join().all(unis).andCollectFailures()
                    .replaceWithVoid();
        }).await().indefinitely();
```

Comment: You can either use withConnection(), withTransaction(). 
withConnection provides a single connection datasource.

Comment: may pipelining in general be explained in the Quarkus documentation?